# generatePom arguments for third-party-jar license?

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

When I deploy a library jar file that is non-Maven into a repository, I can use the `generatePom` switch:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
    -Durl=<pathToRepo>
    -Dfile=<jarFile>
    -DgroupId=<groupId>
    -DartifactId=<artifactId>
    -Dpackaging=jar
    -Dversion=<version>
    -DgeneratePom=true
```

The additional switch `DgeneratePom.description=Hello!` generates `<description>Hello!</description>` in the generated pom.xml file in the repository.

Are there any more switches? What I would really love would be an argument that generates a license block:

```
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>...</name>
        <distribution>...</distribution>
        <url>...</url>
        <comments>...</comments>
    </license>
</licenses>
```

Are there any?

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) which shows all the options?

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. :) So, the answer is "no", am I right?

Comment: Yeah, there's no facility for that. Best bet would be to write your own POM and deploy it manually with [`pomFile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#pomFile).

Comment: I feared that I would have to do it that (long) way. :(